# Who "owns" the ELF spec?

Tags: elf

At some point when a new processor architecture is implemented, the `elf.h` header file needs to be updated. Is there a central authority that "owns" or has responsibility for maintaining a canonical `elf.h`? Is there at least some form of registry for all the different machine type `EM_*` definitions?